# Horizontal spacing in D3 Tree graph

Tags: d3.js

This snippet of code is taken from [here](https://gist.github.com/d3noob/8323795). I made two modifications:

1. Removed the **reverse()** which make no difference.
2. As I understand D3, the nodes are drawn from top to bottom by default. But in this graph it is rotated 90 degree anti-clockwise. Now to make the horizontal position correctly, I changed the code from

**nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 50; });**

to

**nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.x = d.depth * 50; });**

But this wrongly draw the graph, by changing the vertical spacing (**y**) not horizontal spacing (**x**).

Is there a way to draw the graph by using the D3 defaults and then rotate by an angle clockwise or anti-clockwise?

```js
var treeData = [
  {
    "name": "Top Level",
    "parent": "null",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "Level 2: A",
        "parent": "Top Level",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Son of A",
            "parent": "Level 2: A"
          },
          {
            "name": "Daughter of A",
            "parent": "Level 2: A"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Level 2: B",
        "parent": "Top Level"
      }
    ]
  }
];

// ************** Generate the tree diagram  *****************
var margin = {top: 20, right: 120, bottom: 20, left: 120},
 width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
 height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
 
var i = 0;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
 .size([height, width]);

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
 .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
 .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
 .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
 .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

root = treeData[0];
  
update(root);

function update(source) {

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  //var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
   //links = tree.links(nodes);
  
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root),
   links = tree.links(nodes);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  
  /////// nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 200; });
  
  nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.x = d.depth * 50; });

  // Declare the nodes…
  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
   .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

  // Enter the nodes.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
   .attr("class", "node")
   .attr("transform", function(d) { 
    return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });

  nodeEnter.append("circle")
   .attr("r", 10)
   .style("fill", "#fff");

  nodeEnter.append("text")
   .attr("x", function(d) { 
    return d.children || d._children ? -13 : 13; })
   .attr("dy", ".35em")
   .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { 
    return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
   .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
   .style("fill-opacity", 1);

  // Declare the links…
  var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
   .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

  // Enter the links.
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
   .attr("class", "link")
   .attr("d", diagonal);

}
```

```css
 .node circle {
   fill: #fff;
   stroke: steelblue;
   stroke-width: 3px;
 }

 .node text { font: 12px sans-serif; }

 .link {
   fill: none;
   stroke: #ccc;
   stroke-width: 2px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Changing the depth spacing to alter `x` doesn't actually modify the `x` coordinate relative to the svg. If you think about it, changing `y` based on `depth` *is* the default mode of a tree graph. The thing is that in the example, you'll note that on line `73` and `102` that `d.y` is passed as `x`, and `d.x` is passed as `y` which is why the graph is rotated. If you reverse these, you will get a vertical tree, and then you can figure out spacing in a less complicated manner.

Comment: So, before the graph is drawn (line 102), should the defaults be used to set up the tree? So, always use **y** to update the depths (depth0, depth1, depth2 etc...)?

Comment: Basically, yes. Changing the y value should cause the horizontal spacing to increase because the layout is effectively rotated by flipping the x and y values. It's a very simple way to do this, but can also lead to confusing graphical misalignment later on if you forget that the coordinates are swapped.